# Log off an Admin from Quickbooks

Tags: windows-server-2003, admin, quickbooks

Quickbooks is not letting me log in as admin because it says admin is already logged in. I have had everyone in the entire office log off and I have checked all computers and have made sure that no one is logged in as admin.

How can I log the admin off when I can't even log in as admin? It seems the session for admin some how kept even though no one is logged in as admin. Quickbooks and the company file sit on our network server and everyone accesses QuickBooks through the network.

I don't know if this is a problem caused by the server, or by quickbooks, or both.

We are running windows server 2003 with Quickbooks Enterprise Solutions, Wholesale & Management edition.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Restarting the server or restarting the Quickbooks Database server manager service (sometimes called QBDB21) will fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry. That is not a fix.  It is a bug in QB and MUST be fixed.  On Enterprise 2014 this PROBLEM still exists.  Users show as logged in but are NOT.  Rebooting the server is NOT how to fix software bugs.  Please INTUIT.  DO IT RIGHT.